# Curve fitting with python error

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scientific-computing, function-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data to `(cos(x))^n`. The vale of `n` in theory is 2, but my data should give me around 1.7. When I define my fitting function and I try `curve_fit`, I get an error

```
def f(x,a,b,c):
   return a+b*np.power(np.cos(x),c)

param, extras = curve_fit(f, x, y)
```

This is my data

```
x   y               error
90  3.3888756187    1.8408898986
60  2.7662844365    1.6632150903
45  2.137309503     1.4619540017
30  1.5256883339    1.2351875703
0   1.4665463518    1.2110104672
```

The error looks like this:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power   after removing
> the cwd from sys.path.
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:690:
> OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
> category=OptimizeWarning)

Comment: Is there still something missing/not working? If so, let me know that I can modify my answer, if not, please consider to upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: First of all thank you very much, it was really helpful. The problem was that the x data was in degrees and it should be in radians. Other than that I learnt to use of *popt to call all the items in the array so it was great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cos(x)` can become negative and then `cos(x) ^ n` can be undefined. Illustration:

```
np.cos(90)
-0.44807361612917013
```

and e.g.

```
np.cos(90) ** 1.7
nan
```

That causes the two error messages you receive.

It works fine, if you modify your model, e.g. to `a + b * np.cos(c * x + d)`. Then the plot looks as follows:

[image]

The code can be found below with some inline comments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def f(x, a, b, c, d):

    return a + b * np.cos(c * x + d)

# your data
xdata = [90, 60, 45, 30, 0]
ydata = [3.3888756187, 2.7662844365, 2.137309503, 1.5256883339, 1.4665463518]

# plot data
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='data')

# fit the data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=[3., .5, 0.1, 10.])

# plot the result
xdata_new = np.linspace(0, 100, 200)
plt.plot(xdata_new, f(xdata_new, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```